# probability of candidate A always ahead of candidate B in the counting of votes.

Tags: probability

Let's candidate $A$ and $B$ have number of votes $n$ and $m$ respectively, show that the probability of candidate A always ahead of candidate B in the counting of the votes is $\frac{n-m}{n+m}$.

Sol: let $p_{n,m}$ denote the respective probability, then $p_{n,m}= p(\text{A is always ahead}/\text{A received last vote})+p(\text{A is always ahead}/\text{B received last vote})$.

Ok so now what? What is $P_{0,0}$? according to the formula, it is $\frac{0}{0}$ but it should be $0$. Also, $P_{0,1}=-1$ which doesn't make sense. Need to use induction.

Comment: This is known as [Bertrand's Ballot Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem).

Comment: The theorem assumes $n>m\ge 0$ because otherwise A is not ahead at the end of counting

Comment: Oh OK!  that makes sense!